# histogram with errorbars, pb with the titles of the columns

Tags: gnuplot

these are my data : TABLE11-mol+func.dat

```
#mol  PBE     optPBE        optB86b       BEEF       Exp      IncertitudeBEEF    0 
0    PBE-PBE  optPBE-vdW1  optB86b-vdW1  BEEF-vdW2  Exp       Incert.BEEF        0
1    0.014   0.226         0.210         0.125     0.155          0.10444        0  
2    0.033   0.362         0.392         0.223      0             0.16794        0
3    1.742   1.755         2.152         1.432     1.36             0.29116      0
4    1.206   1.441         1.724         1.115      0             0.17857        0
5    0.934   1.533         1.857         1.063       0            0.30034        0
6    0.777   1.514         1.843         0.959     1.295            0.31264      0
7    2.018   2.298         2.858         1.751       0             0.37737       0
8    1.084   1.648         2.336         1.033     1.762            0.60643      0
9    1.504   2.355         3.451         1.449     2.694            1.0138       0
```

this is my code :

```
set key left
set auto x
set ylabel "- E_{ads} (eV)" font "Times-Roman, 18"
set yrange [0:3.5]
set ytics (0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5) font "Times-Roman, 18"
set style data histograms
set style histogram errorbars lw 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set xtics ("Methane" 0, "Ethane" 1, "Ethylidyne" 2, "Ethylene" 3, "Butene" 4,  "Cyclohexene" 5, "Butadiene" 6, "Benzene" 7, "Naphtalene" 8) font "Times-Roman, 15"
set xtic nomirror rotate by -45 scale 0 
set grid y
plot 'TABLE11-mol+func.dat' using 2:8 ti col, '' u 3:8 ti col, '' u 4:8 ti col, '' u 5:7 ti col, '' u 6:8 ti col
```

this gives an histogram with wrong title for each color

so I tried to add them "with my hands" with this line instead of the last one :

```
plot 'TABLE11-mol+func.dat' using 2:8 ti 'PBE', '' u 3:8 ti 'optPBE', '' u 4:8 ti 'optB86b', '' u 5:7 ti 'BEEF', '' u 6:8 ti 'Exp'
```

and this messes up my histogram, with weird stuffs who appear all over the diagram, and it adds an xtic and bars...

somebody could help me ?

it's even more weird because it use to work some month ago... maybe it's because I have a new version of gnuplot ?

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot fails to select the correct column to get the title from. It tries to always use the 8th column, as given by the second column in the `using` option, although this gives the error estimate and not the y-value. You must explicitely give the column number as e.g. `ti col(3)`:

```
set key left
set yrange [0:3.5]
set ytics 0.5
set style data histograms
set style histogram errorbars lw 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set xtics ("Methane" 0, "Ethane" 1, "Ethylidyne" 2, "Ethylene" 3, "Butene" 4,  "Cyclohexene" 5, "Butadiene" 6, "Benzene" 7, "Naphtalene" 8)
set xtic nomirror rotate by -45 scale 0 
set grid y
plot 'TABLE11-mol+func.dat' u 2:8 t col(2), '' u 3:8 t col(3), '' u 4:8 t col(4), '' u 5:7 t col(5), '' u 6:8 t col(6)
```

[image]

Comment: ok, I understand. But now it doesn't like the command "lot" :     gnuplot> lot for [i=2:6] 'TABLE11-mol+func.dat' using i:8 ti col(i)
         ^
         "TABLE11-mol+func-stackof.gnu", line 11: invalid command

Comment: Ups, copy&paste error from my side. That should of course be `plot ...`, see the update.

Comment: ok thank you ! it works but doesn't give me the error bars anymore.

Comment: The iteration was wrong since you use different columns for the error bars. I updated the answer.

Comment: with this it's finally ok: plot 'TABLE11-mol+func-justEads.dat' using 2:8 ti col(2), '' u 3:8 ti col(3), '' u 4:8 ti col(4), '' u 5:7 ti col(5), '' u 6:8 ti col(6)